# Tabla pierde CSS al hacer una petición AJAX

Tags: php, css, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo una tabla la cual formo con una consulta (disculpen si mi código no es el óptimo pero estoy empezando):

```php
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="main-card mb-3 card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $palabras['pml']['tabla_titulo'];?>  <?php echo $zona." - ".$mercado; ?></h5>
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div>
                      <?php 
                      $sql = "SELECT zona_carga, AVG($pml_mercado) as promedio, MAX($pml_mercado) as maximo, MIN($pml_mercado) as minimo, STDDEV($pml_mercado) as desviacion FROM dbs4370013.load_zone_data where zona_carga='$zona' and fecha between '$fecha_ini' and '$fecha_fin' order by fecha, hora asc;";
                      $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
                      echo "
                            <table id=\"tabla_pml\" class=\"display mb-0 table table table-fit\">
                            <thead>  
                            <tr>
                            <th>".$palabras['componentes']['origen']."</th>
                            <th>".$palabras['componentes']['mercado']."</th>
                            <th>".$palabras['componentes']['promedio']."</th>
                            <th>".$palabras['componentes']['maximo']."</th>
                            <th>".$palabras['componentes']['minimo']."</th>
                            <th>".$palabras['componentes']['desviacion']."</th>
                              </tr>
                              </thead>";
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                            $promedio=round($row[1]/$moneda,2);
                            $maximo=round($row[2]/$moneda,2);
                            $minimo=round($row[3]/$moneda,2);
                            $desviacion=round($row[4]/$moneda,2);
                            echo "
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td>".$row[0]."</td>
                                <td>".$mercado."</td>
                                <td>".$promedio."</td>
                                <td>".$maximo."</td>
                                <td>".$minimo."</td>
                                <td>".$desviacion."</td>
                              </tr>
                              </tbody>";
                          }
                    echo "</table>";
                      
                      
                      ?>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto me arroja una tabla correctamente formada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al momento de hacer una llamada en ajax para que cargue otra ciudad la tabla regresa, sin el CSS, pero con los datos correctos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría hacer para que cuando la llame con los nuevos valores no se deforme ya que pierde todo formato?

Comment: Diría que no se pierde el CSS, sino más bien que se pierde el formato del datatable.

Comment: ¿Porque no incluir el CSS en tu pregunta? Además, ten en cuenta el riesgo de inyección SQL.

Comment: Como haces la llamada ajax, intenta user el formato recomendado para DataTables, https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Comment: Deberiamos ver la funcion de retorno en PHP de la llamada en AJAX, para ver si devuelve correctamente las clases de la tabla `class=\"display mb-0 table table table-fit\"` o ver exactamente que devuelve. Así como el elemento que vas a sustituir (¿quizás es `tabla_pml`?  ¿Quizás estas poniendo una tabla dentro de otra tabla sin querer?)

Comment: Fue un error mio al no incluir la libreria en la pagina de consulta, ha quedado solucionado.